# Import SVN tag directly into workspace using Subversion

Tags: java, eclipse, svn, tortoisesvn, subversive

I created a local repository using TortoiseSVN. I created a few tags with a few versions of my java project during development in it.

I installed Subversive eclipse plugin. I'm trying to import the tagged version of my project directly into the workspace.

When I try to use `Import -> Project from SVN` from Eclipse menu, I only get the option to import the `trunk`, but not `tags`.

I can open Subversive perspective and check out tags from there. But, in that case the files are just copied to my workspace directory from the SVN repository tag, but I must then manually import that project into the workspace using `Import -> Existing Projects into Workspace`.

Is there any way I can import tags directly?

My motivation for this is that I created a Java training task which has 4 parts that build up on each other. So, I want  to have trainees access project implementation in 4 different phases. That's why I used 4 tags.

Comment: You need to add the tags in eclipse if I remember correctly

Comment: I don't mean to start a discussion on git vs svn but with git you can just add 4 commits and then checkout specific commits and your IDE will reflect these changes immediately

Comment: @PeterGelderbloem I see the tags from Eclipse. The problem is that when I check out. It checks out at working directory which is in my workspace, but the project doesn't appear in Eclipse. And, when I try to do it using import -> project from SVN. I do not see the tags.

Comment: each tag will be on it's own URL so you can navigate to the correct one in the Select Folder step in the wizard